# Python json.dumps() with writing JSON string to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I am writing to a CSV file, where one of the column values is a large JSON string. I am trying to understand how to escape the comma values in the JSON so it does not write them as individual columns in the CSV file.

I need this solution without using the traditional csv library as I want to understand the writing of data to files better.

```
import json

# Emulating the process
d: dict = {"foo":"bar", "py": "pi"}
json_list: list[str] = [json.dumps(d)]

with open("file_test.csv", mode='a+') as f:
    f.write('col_a,')
    f.write('col_b,'+ '\n')
    f.write(','.join(json_list)+'\n')
```

Output is a CSV like:

```
col_a,col_b
"{""foo"": ""bar"""," ""py"": ""pi""}"
```

I only want a single column filled (col_b is empty). Do I have to replace every comma with an escaped comma in the json string (the strings can be several MB large) or is there a more optimal way using a built-in json method?

Comment: why wouldn't you just use the `csv` library to write the CSV?

Comment: If a column contains actual commas, the usual solution is to put quotes around it.  But in your case, the column ALSO contains literal quotes, so it's a lot more complicated.

Comment: "as I want to understand the writing of data to files better." doesn't seem to be working too well. You could inspect its source code if you want to know how it works

Comment: The optimal way is to use the `csv` module.

Comment: @roganjosh I am using ```aiofiles``` for asynchronous writing, not the standard library  ```csv```. ```aiofiles``` functions like the standard library blocking API for file writing and I am customizing it to suit my needs. Given that my issue is related to the standard file writing API, I presented a sample like this instead of ```aiofiles``` as I do not want to get bogged down with async discussion. No need to be rude.

Comment: How was I rude?

Comment: @roganjosh your second comment.

Comment: Is it factually incorrect? You can inspect the source code if you want to understand  how it works and your code is failing. Your code also makes a very weak effort at addressing the problem for someone apparently interested in getting into the details of the issue

Comment: note, you can *still* use `csv` to generate the string, then write that string using `aiofiles` asynchronously.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I ended up taking a look at the ```aiocsv``` library. I initially figured that by writing the CSV string using the ```csv``` library, it would block the main thread. Is this not true?

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the value in quotes and escape all the other quotes as below:

```
import json

d: dict = {"foo":"bar", "py": "pi"}
json_list: list[str] = [json.dumps(d)]

with open("file_test.csv", mode='a+') as f:
    f.write('col_a,')
    f.write('col_b,'+ '\n')
    cell = ','.join(json_list)
    escaped = cell.replace('"', '""')
    f.write('"' + escaped + '"\n')
```

I would recommend using the `csv` module or using tab separation if you want to make it simpler.

If you actually want each item in your json_list on a new row (but in the first column only), use this:

```
import json

d: dict = {"foo":"bar", "py": "pi"}
json_list: list[str] = [json.dumps(d)]

with open("file_test.csv", mode='a+') as f:
    f.write('col_a,')
    f.write('col_b,'+ '\n')
    for cell in json_list:
        escaped = cell.replace('"', '""')
        f.write('"' + escaped + '"\n')
```

Comment: @JonSG yes assuming that you want to preserve the \ and not hide it.

Comment: There's no json.loads, there's only representing data in a CSV.

Comment: Actually, I think it does work, my bad